# Insert two objects at once in database c#

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a database with three tables Player, Game and Role. The relationship between those three tables is shown through another table called PlayerGameRole which contains the IDs of the three tables as foreign keys and are also primary keys to the PlayerGameRole table. 
Currently, I am trying to add a new Player and at the same time populate the PlayerGameRole  with the corresponding IDs. However, I am able to execute the API but my code does not populate the table with the given information.

```
public Player AddPlayer(Player player){
 using (DBContext db = new DBContext())
        {
            db.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
            Player p = new Player();
            p.Name = player.Name;
            p.Email = player.Email;            
            p.PlayerGameRole = player.PlayerGameRole;
            db.Player.Add(p);


            db.SaveChanges();

            return p;
        }
      }
```

There is my PlayerModel:

```
public partial class Player{

    [DataMember]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [Required]
    [StringLength(75)]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [DataMember]
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<PlayerGameRole> PlayerGameRole { get; set; }

}
```

Comment: Where do you use Linq?

Comment: "does not populate" - any exceptions or what?

Comment: No exception. It just does not add the data to the table PlayerGameRole.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think problem is here

```
p.PlayerGameRole = player.PlayerGameRole
```

try to create collection explicitly and add elements:

```
p.PlayerGameRole = new List<PlayerGameRole>();
foreach(var role in player.PlayerGameRole)
{
p.PlayerGameRole.Add(role);
}
```

Comment: Thank you! :D You saved me hours of banging my head against the table